# Convert Mysql query in Postgresql query

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is there an utility to convert mysql query in postgresql query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also the [PostgreSQL-wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL).

Answer (score 7):

For DDL you can use mysqldump (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL)

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql databasename > outputfile.sql
```

For DML I don't know of a tool that would automatically adjust queries from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Comment: you can also use the `-d` flag to get only the tables creation sql.

Comment: also use ```SET standard_conforming_strings = 'off';
SET backslash_quote = 'on';``` in dump first lines

Answer (score 4):

Go to  http://www.sqlines.com/online  select left side mysql in source past your mysql query and select right side select postgresql in target then click left side on convert button

Comment: Handy if you just have a short snippet to convert. It doesn't preserve field comments from CREATE TABLE statements, however.

Comment: It's non commercial. Any free option there?